# Redefinition of 'RCTLogLevel' error shows in xcode 8.2

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook, react-native, reactjs

I created iOS app using react-native(0.40).But i always got error like Redefinition of 'RCTLogLevel’.Here i attached one screenshot.Please go through this.How to solve this issue?

[image]

Comment: Can you check what version of react-native-vector-icons are you using now? v4.0.0 is needed to run with React Native >=0.40.

Comment: how to check 'react-native-vector-icons' version?

Comment: Try run `npm list --depth=0` and look for react-native-vector-icons.

Comment: please come to this link http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135233/react-native

Answer (score 0):

upgrade react-native-vector-icons version.

React Native 4.0 [Breaking Changes iOS native headers moved](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/releases/tag/v0.40.0)

Comment: `$ npm install react-native-vector-icons --save` `$ react-native link`  [this](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons)

Comment: I used the following command to update 'react-native-vector-icons' , npm install --save react-native-vector-icons@4.0